# How to reuse the component

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio, components, accordion

Factor is a component and Idea is an another component I need to show all the data's of Factor in the Component Idea.Can anyone say How to reuse the component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@Input()` for passing data into child component, and `@Output()` for emitting event from child component. You can refer to the documentation for more clarity https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Answer (score 0):

*you creat a component like :*

```
 ng g component xyz
```

> after using selector reuse component Like

=> `<app-xyz(component-Name)></app-xyz(component-Name))`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ok sir i will change formate